# MAC crashed - Installing Ubuntu as single boot

Tags: installation, mac

My new mac book pro crashed. Yes, I have the warranty & apple guys will replace the hdd but I do not want this crappy apple now. I'd rather consider setting up ubuntu on this hardware.

I've taken out mac book's original hdd (that crashed) and got a new external disk.
I intend to use this new hdd with ubuntu installed on my Mac. There is no working copy of mac os in the original mac disk now.

I've seen several posts suggesting I can install ubuntu on the disk and I have already done the install on my new external disk.

The problem I am facing at the moment is once I take out the Ubuntu install CD and try to boot the MAC with the new hdd (ubuntu), it doesn't start up. This new hdd is connected as external disk only (via a usb connector).

1. Should I put it inside the MAC instead.?
2. Are there any issues using Ubuntu as single boot on MAC?
3. What about MAC firmware updates?

Any points / inputs will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Now i'm no wizard at replacing OS on funky hardware, but I've been told that (possibly) the easiest way to get Ubuntu on a mac is to run boot camp and do it through there, and then deleting the OSX partition in the process, but seeing the current state that you're in, I would try just running Ubuntu from the HDD and hoping for the best